# Can't remove whitespaces in string

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

My script reads txt file and then writes values into database table. There is a field with price, and in txt file price with 4 digit values have whitespace after first digit (2 500 ex.). I put this function (str_replace works well and replaced ',' but when I use it for removing whitespace it does not do it, and finally I put preg_replace but it also skips whitespace):

```
$model->price = preg_replace('/\s+/','',str_replace(',', '.', $row_data[3]));
```

datatype of price field in my table is varchar, when I used int or decimal it skips digits after space (2 070 becomes 2, 12 015 => 12). I have to remove this space in integration stage, because when I do operations with price field php skips digits after space and I have errors in my further manipulations.

What is the problem guys?

**UPD** Solution from @jeroen works great, I changed field of price to decimal (10,2) and put this line for parsing the string with price:

```
$model->price = filter_var(str_replace(',', '.', $row_data[3]), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use a regex but a [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for that:

```
// replace if necessary
$number = str_replace(',', '.', $row_data[3]);

// filter unwanted characters
$model->price = filter_var($number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

And you should make sure that you update all your prices in the database so that you can switch to a numerical value in the database itself.

Comment: I can delete existed, it's not a problem. Should I change datatype for price?

Comment: @Eugene Of course, you might want to order by price or search for price ranges in the future so a numerical value is always preferred. Integers or decimals though as floats will lead to rounding errors.

Comment: Whitespaces has gone, but now it removed my '.' from price, such as 35.75 become 3575

Comment: @Eugene Ooops, sorry, forgot to add the correct flag. See my edit and http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `str_replace` on the spaces too? Would be much easier than a regex

```
str_replace(array(',', ' '), array('.', ''), $row_data[3]);
```